# I don't understand why $\mu$ is not complete

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set with at least two element. Consider the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ as $\mathcal A=\{\phi,X\}$ and a measure on $\mathcal A$ defined by $$\mu(\phi)=0\\\mu(X)=1$$

My [note](http://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/mtnair/public_html/Meas-Int-Crash-Course-1.pdf) ($2.12$) says $\mu$ is *not* complete. But I don't understand why? [Since any subset of the empty set is empty]

Comment: Could be an uncanonical definition of a complete measure. More likely, just a mistake. Yes, by the usual understanding of a complete measure, $\mu$ is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case and according to your notes, $\mu$ is complete:
$$
\mu(A) = 0 \Rightarrow A = \emptyset \rightarrow [E\subset A \Rightarrow A\in 
\mathcal A ]
$$

Now for a working example, take
$$\Omega = \{1, 2, 3\}
\\
\mathcal A = \sigma( \{1,2\} )
\\
\mu(A)=  \text{card}  (A \cap \{3\} )
$$then
$\mu(\{1,2\}) = 0$ and $\{1\}\notin \mathcal A = \{
\emptyset;\{3\};\{1,2\};\{1,2,3\}
\}
$